# Get value from td after .closest() .find() .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to assign the value from a `<td>` to a variable. I find the `<td>` by using the jQuery `closest()` and `find()` methods.

If I `alert` the `<td>` it gives me the correct value but if I `console.log()` it it doesn't. It returns an object.

```js
function getval(sel) {
  var thisTaskID = $(".selTaskOwner").on("change", function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var foundTaskID = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    alert(foundTaskID);
  });

  console.log(thisTaskID);
}
```

How do I get the value of the found `<td>` into a variable?

I've tried using `text()`, `val()` and `html()` at the end of `thisTaskID` but nothing works.

Thanks in advance, as you can guess I'm new

Comment: The value is already in a variable: `foundTaskID`. `thisTaskID` is a jQuery object holding the `.selTaskOwner` elements. You seem a little confused about how this code is working.

Comment: I'm assuming foundTaskID is just within the scope of this function, so could I declare a global variable and assign foundTaskID to it?

Comment: Yes that's possible, but it's very far from good practice. What exactly is the issue? If you want to do something with `foundTaskID` call another function in the `change` event handler and pass it as an argument

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. A jQuery object. And use the variable as an argument to a function. Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the value on selection change event, therefor you need no other function for it. Probably anything you need is this:

```
var foundTaskID = 0;
$(".selTaskOwner").on("change", function() {
    foundTaskID = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").html();
    /* Do what you want with it... */
    console.log(thisTaskID);
    alert(foundTaskID);
});
```